# Getting a deb with wget problem

Tags: downloads, wget, zsh

I'm trying to get Anki like this:

```
wget https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
```

(That's the latest version) gives me:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: wget https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
```

I'm writing an install script for my system, the same worked with Skype and GoogleChrome, not sure what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the script or the command. But for your confirmation I am giving my log here

```
frank-Jai% wget https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
--2013-08-02 19:09:12--  https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
Resolving anki.googlecode.com (anki.googlecode.com)... 74.125.135.82, 2404:6800:4001:c01::52
Connecting to anki.googlecode.com (anki.googlecode.com)|74.125.135.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2958570 (2.8M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘anki-2.0.12.deb’

100%[======================================>] 29,58,570   52.0KB/s   in 53s    

2013-08-02 19:10:07 (54.1 KB/s) - ‘anki-2.0.12.deb’ saved [2958570/2958570]
```

I have done the same thing by writing some script as you are trying to do. here is the log ,

```
frank-Jai% cat install.sh 
#!/bin/zsh
wget https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
done
```

output:

```
frank-Jai% chmod +x install.sh
frank-Jai% ./install.sh 
--2013-08-02 19:15:08--  https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb
Resolving anki.googlecode.com (anki.googlecode.com)... 74.125.135.82, 2404:6800:4001:c01::52
Connecting to anki.googlecode.com (anki.googlecode.com)|74.125.135.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2958570 (2.8M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘anki-2.0.12.deb.1’
```

see and verify with your script to get the where mistake is.

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: wtf it works now, I can't explain that!